# Formula notation for scatterplot producing unexpected results

Tags: r, dataframe, plot, colors

I am working on a map, where the color of each point is proportional to one response variable, and the size of the point is proportional to another. I've noticed that when I try to plot the points using formula notation things go haywire, while default notation performs as expected. I have used formula notation to plot maps many times before, and thought that the notations were nearly interchangeable. Why would these produce different results? I have read through the `plot.formula` and `plot.default` documentation and haven't been able to figure it out. Based on [this](http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-help-with-plot-td810106.html) I am wondering if it has to do with the columns of `dat` being coerced to factors, but I'm not sure why that would be happening. Any ideas?

Consider the following example data frame, `dat`:

```
latitude <- c(runif(10, min = 45, max = 48))
latitude[9] <- NA
longitude <- c(runif(10, min = -124.5, max = -122.5))
longitude[9] <- NA
color <- c("#00FFCCCC", "#99FF00CC", "#FF0000CC", "#3300FFCC", "#00FFCCCC",
           "#00FFCCCC", "#3300FFCC", "#00FFCCCC",          NA, "#3300FFCC")
size <- c(4.916667, 5.750000, 7.000000, 2.000000, 5.750000, 
          4.500000, 2.000000, 4.500000,       NA, 2.000000)
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(longitude, latitude, color, size))
```

Plotting according to formula notation

```
plot(latitude ~ longitude, data = dat, type = "p", pch = 21, col = 1, bg = color, cex = size)
```

produces 
[this mess](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qlI5a.png) and the following error: `graphical parameter "type" is obsolete`.

Plotting according to the default notation

```
plot(longitude, latitude, type = "p", pch = 21, col = 1, bg = color, cex = size)
```

works [as expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f0v2i.png), though with the same error.

Comment: It must be the data type, because `plot(as.numeric(latitude) ~ as.numeric(longitude), data = dat, type = "p", pch = 21, col = 1, bg = color, cex=as.numeric(dat$size))` worked fine for me.

Comment: @mysteRious You are right that it runs, but the colors are off which is still concerning. But if I follow your train of thought and run `plot(as.numeric(latitude) ~ as.numeric(longitude), data = dat, type = "p", pch = 21, col = 1, bg = as.vector(dat$color), cex = as.numeric(dat$size))` it works. So it definitely has to be the data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with this. First is that your use of `cbind` is turning this into a `matrix`, albeit temporarily, which is converting your numbers to `character`. See:

```
dat <- as.data.frame(cbind(longitude, latitude, color, size))
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ longitude: Factor w/ 9 levels "-122.855375511572",..: 6 8 9 1 4 3 2 7 NA 5
#  $ latitude : Factor w/ 9 levels "45.5418886151165",..: 6 2 4 1 3 7 5 9 NA 8
#  $ color    : Factor w/ 4 levels "#00FFCCCC","#3300FFCC",..: 1 3 4 2 1 1 2 1 NA 2
#  $ size     : Factor w/ 5 levels "2","4.5","4.916667",..: 3 4 5 1 4 2 1 2 NA 1
```

If instead you *just* use `data.frame`, you'll get:

```
dat <- data.frame(longitude, latitude, color, size)
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ longitude: num  -124 -124 -124 -123 -124 ...
#  $ latitude : num  47.3 45.9 46.3 45.5 46 ...
#  $ color    : Factor w/ 4 levels "#00FFCCCC","#3300FFCC",..: 1 3 4 2 1 1 2 1 NA 2
#  $ size     : num  4.92 5.75 7 2 5.75 ...
plot(latitude ~ longitude, data = dat, pch = 21, col = 1, bg = color, cex = size)
```

[image]

But now the colors are all dorked. Okay, the problem is likely because your `$color` is a factor, which is being interpreted internally as integers. Try `stringsAsFactors=F`:

```
dat <- data.frame(longitude, latitude, color, size, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
str(dat)
# 'data.frame': 10 obs. of  4 variables:
#  $ longitude: num  -124 -124 -124 -123 -124 ...
#  $ latitude : num  47.3 45.9 46.3 45.5 46 ...
#  $ color    : chr  "#00FFCCCC" "#99FF00CC" "#FF0000CC" "#3300FFCC" ...
#  $ size     : num  4.92 5.75 7 2 5.75 ...
plot(latitude ~ longitude, data = dat, pch = 21, col = 1, bg = color, cex = size)
```

[image]